# Is it possible to attach an event to a PSObject?

Tags: events, powershell, powershell-3.0, psobject

Say I've a psobject like this :

```
$o=New-Object PSObject -Property @{"value"=0}
Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "Sqrt" -Value {
    echo "the square root of $($this.value) is $([Math]::Round([Math]::Sqrt($this.value),2))"
} -inputObject $o
```

Is it possible to attach an event so that the method Sqrt() is executed when the value attribute change ? ie :

```
PS>$o.value=9
```

will produce

```
the square root of 9 is 3
```

### update

As per @Richard answer this is the working recipe :

```
$o=New-Object PSObject -property @{"_val"=1}
Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "Sqrt" -Value {
    write-host "the square root of $($this._val) is $([Math]::Round([Math]::Sqrt($this._val),2))"
} -inputObject $o


Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'val' -Value{ $this._val }  -SecondValue { $this._val=$args[0];$this.Sqrt() } -inputObject $o
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than making `value` a `NoteProperty` make it a `ScriptProperty`, this includes defining separate get and set methods that are called rather than directly modifying a field.

```
$theObject | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'Value' 
                        -Value{ $this._value }
                        -SecondValue { $this._value = $args[0]; $this.Sqrt }
```

(`Value` defines the get method, `SecondValue` the set.)

Note as PowerShell doesn't provide any ability to encapsulate data, the underlying field is still accessible to callers. Coding a custom type in C# (or other .NET language) and use of `Add-Type` can avoid this, but is unlikely to be worth it unless you really have callers who will not follow the rules.

**Second Issue**

In a ScriptProperty there is no output pipe (any output is thrown away), so `echo` (being an alias for `Write-Output`) won't do anything useful. Replacing it with `Write-Host` works. In general side effects in a property get or set (including output) are poor practice (there is an expectation of low overhead when using them).

Comment: You've defined `val` in terms of itself. The underlying field has to be a different name (notice the `_` prefix I used).

Comment: Oups, thanks. But, now the underlying field is modified but the method is not executed. I've updated my post.

Comment: do you mean this is a bad practice?

Comment: @Kayasax: Using a property for side effects: Yes. (However I would say "poor" rather than "bad": there are far worse practices out there :-(.)

Comment: OK. But in this case it will be made on purpose (I was thinking about something like onChange or onSubmit events in javascript)

Comment: thanks again this allowed me to do lazy loading un my profile :)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751430/lazy-loading-in-powershell