# It is possible to add an event to custom objects in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a custom object in powershell.
This object must raise an event, but there is no way to assign an event name with new-event CMDLET.
I tired to add an event with add-member cmdlet, but powershell returns an issue that says "is not possible to assign an event to PSObject".
Thereis an other way to perform this action?
Thanks in advance.
Germano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CmdLets `Register-EngineEvent` and `New-Event` may help you to register and fire your own events :

With `New-Event` you must specifie

- `-SourceIdentifier`  : Your own identifier

You should specifie

- `-Sender` : the object that emit the event
- `-EventArguments` : an array of arguments
- `-MessageData` : a parameter object

Here is an example :

```
New-Event -SourceIdentifier "MyOwnEvent" -EventArguments "A Param"
```

Cmdlet `Register-EngineEvent` allow your code to subscribe to Windows PowerShell engine events, but also to the events fired by `New-Event`.

```
$evt1 = Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier "MyOwnEvent" -Action {[console]::Beep(500,500)}
```

So now your object can have a *note property* called *Event1* with the value "MyOwnEvent" a piece of code can register to this event with `Register-EngineEvent` and you object can fire this event with `New-Event`.

Answer (score 0):

-Edit, sorry misread the question.  Did a quick search and turned up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18865680/is-it-possible-to-attach-an-event-to-a-psobject)

```
$o=New-Object PSObject -property @{"_val"=1}

Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name "Sqrt" -Value {

 write-host "the square root of $($this._val) is $([Math]::Round([Math]::Sqrt($this._val),2))"
} -inputObject $o

Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name 'val' -Value{ $this._val }  -SecondValue { $this._val=$args[0];$this.Sqrt() } -inputObject $o
```